# Cardinality of intersection of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the following problem: find $n(A \cap B)$ if $n(A)=10$, $n(B)=13$ and $n(A \cup B) = 15$.

I know if I want to find the union I use the Cardinal Number formula:

$$n(A\cup B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A\cap B)$$

But how do I do it the other way: to find $n(A\cap B)$?

Would it be $n(A\cap B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A\cup B)$ ?

Comment: Yes, these four things are numbers.  $A=B+C-D$ can be rearranged to be $D=B+C-A$.

Comment: @vadim123 can you please tell me the answer to the equation?

Comment: @MethodManX What did you get as an answer? Your formula is correct. Maybe there is another source of misunderstanding. If you are not sure about your formula, maybe we can help you if you tell us the source of confusion.

Comment: Your suggested formula is correct. Or else you can substitute in the first formula, and get $15=10+13-n(A\cap B)$ and now find $n(A\cap B)$.

Comment: You could think of it this way, since Venn diagrams can seem a bit abstract.  There are 10 people, say, wearing a badge marked 'A', and 13 with a badge marked 'B'.  Altogether, the number of people wearing a badge (since nothing stops someone from wearing one of each) is 15 [ $ \ A \cup B \ $ , which covers everyone].  Since all of this is the case, how many people would _have_ to be wearing two badges [the $ \ A \cap B \ $ crowd] ?

Comment: Way to make an effort with the the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes... $n(A\cap B) = n(A) + n(B) - n(A\cup B)$ is the way to go.

$n(A\cap B) = 8$ according to this.

A little Venn to visualize the formula:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful........... :)

Answer (score 6):

We know that: $n(A)=10$, $n(B)=13$ and $n(A \cup B) = 15$.

Using the Cardinal Number formula:

$$\underbrace{n(A\cup B)}_{15} = \underbrace{n(A)}_{10} + \underbrace{n(B)}_{13} - n(A\cap B)\tag{1}$$

So indeed, we can write the equivalent to $(1)$: $$n(A\cap B) = \underbrace{n(A)}_{10} + \underbrace{n(B)}_{13} - \underbrace{n(A\cup B)}_{15}\tag{2}$$

$$\text{So, given what we know}:\;\; n(A\cap B) = 10 + 13 - 15 = 8$$

Comment: you own these sorts of questions! +1

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The reason why this works lies in that "n" consists of a function which maps sets to cardinal numbers (which are sets too in set theory, but that doesn't matter here).  So, for n(A), n(B), and so on, we can treat n(A) just like any other sort of number, and thus use variables, and write things n(A)=x, n(B)=y, n(A∪B)=z and so on.  Thus, we can prove that n(A∩B)=n(A)+n(B)−n(A∪B) follows from n(A∪B)=n(A)+n(B)−n(A∩B) using the basic properties of ordinary algebra.